# get random users each time based on the meta key

Tags: user-meta, users

I have many users on my website, out of some has status "elite". I am saving this status in meta key/value  for each user (`'meta_key' => 'elite_member', 'meta_value' => '1'`).

I want to display randomly 2 user profiles in rotation on my site home page
which has status "elite" so that each user profiles will appear same no. of times in rotation. I am able to get all the users with meta_key "elite" and meta_value="1"

```
$elite_members=get_users(array('meta_key' => 'elite_member', 'meta_value' => '1'));
```

But I am not able to get how to display 2 user profiles in rotation so that each user will get same no. of chance to appear on home page.

Answer (score 1):

As `get_users` does not support the `order_by` random, you could shuffle the array after calling the function.

If you want to distribute it even, you could make another `meta_value`, where you store the number of appearances per user, and call the `get_users` with this new `meta_key` in ascending `sort_order` - this way the user with the least appearances will be shown on the homepage.

Comment: could u pls write example of how to call get_users with new meta_key in ascending sort_order? I am not able to do that after looking the get_users parameters.Thanks